# Combining a PyQt Gui app with an Django project

Tags: python, django, pyqt

My question is as follows:
I have a PyQt Gui app. Now I want to publish some of my data to a webserver.
So other people can get acces to it without having the PyQt Gui App.

I am very new to Django. I've read only some first articles and examples.

So my question is:
Is it a feasable way to use django? Are there other quite easier possibilities?
The PyQt App uses also SQlite3 databases.
If I would use django, can I integrate these databases to django?

Thanks for your answers!!!

Comment: https://github.com/ZedObaia/django-pyqt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I understand, you want to publish some of the data *in your SQLite* databases via a website. This is a perfectly valid use of Django and it is totally feasible.

However, this is not the typical way to use Django: you see, Django projects typically define their database structures automatically using abstraction classes (called *models* in the Django terminology). If you want to use your existing database, that is perfectly fine and possible but it requires some reading. Make sure you read the basic Django tutorials and then check out this document: [Integrating django with legacy databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: Please excuse me when I am a little bit clumsy in using this forum, because I am not yet a "professional"!  I start reading and maybe you can response to another point beside this problem.  When I will start another project like this can I start a django project with database and only writing a desktop python gui app which will access the django databases. Is this a possible/good way to do this?

Comment: The databases created by django are generally very well structured and useful. For your next project it can make sense to start defining your models from a django perspective, and then use your PyQT app to make queries to the django-defined database. I'm curious though, if you already need a web app, why not go 100% web? why do you need a PyQt App?

Comment: This post for 4 years ago but I need to sure from one question: Could I use PYQT with Django to create a desktop application?